# How to draw squares from points?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glsl

Is there a possibility to just have one coordinate in the vertex buffer, but still draw a square (two GL_TRIANGLES, or a GL_QUADS)?

How would my vertex shader look like to archive this?

```
float vertices[]={
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0 
}
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// drawing?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometry shader (passthrough Vertex Shader) can do this or you can use GL_POINTS, too, although  some OpenGL implementations have surprisingly small maximum point sizes.

It will probably not be as efficient as passing a proper quad directly.

Comment: Careful with `GL_POINTS` though, some OpenGL implementations have laughably small maximum point sizes.